# Get the content of a DIV and save to a file, jQuery/JS or Server-side

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, file, save

In my site I need to get content of one of DIV and save the content to a file.

I'm just wondering whether is there possibility to to do it in jQuery or JS if not do I have to use server based language like PHP.

Or any one got example or tutorial relative this query?

Comment: You can do this client-side with Flash (or store the data in a cookie), or server-side with your language of choice.

Why do you want to store the raw contents of a div in a file?

Comment: Its just like signature of the user, even like vCard

Comment: Are you looking to save the file on the server or on the client? Flash, Silverlight or Java Applet would be your options for client side saving and AJAX to post the contents of a DIV to the server would be the way to do it for a server file.

Comment: I did something like this a while back (before jQuery if I may date myself). It was a Javascript that took information from a hidden form field and sent it to a text file.  Unfortunately that was a long time ago, I've changed jobs several times and I don't have the source. I bet you could find something if you Google it. Matter of fact I think it was for an event reminder for Outlook. (I want to say it was an iCal?) The good news is there's a plugin for this: http://keith-wood.name/icalendar.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery's AJAX function to send the information to a script on the server that would create and save the file on the server.

Directly you cant use jQuery or JS to this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery, access the content of the div using .text();

Then use jquery ajax function to POST this to a PHP script. Inside the php script you should open a file stream using fopen() with "w+" permission and then use fwrite() to write the contents into the file.

Comment: .text() will get the readable text, using .html() to get the raw html content

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the [HTML5 Filesystem API](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/) to save the file in the browser and use [`a[download]`](http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/a.download.html) to present the user with a download link. Alternatively, you could skip the Filesystem and just do the latter.